# Connection String to access 2007

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

Im using this code to connect to access 2007 database :

```
   public void RetrieveData(){

        OleDbConnection conn=null;
        OleDbDataReader reader=null;
   string strConnection= @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\School.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"; 

        try
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Class", conn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataList1.DataSource = reader;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.Message);
            Response.End();

        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) reader.Close();
            if (conn != null) conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

but when i run it it jus give blank page.in debug mode I can see that the database property of conn is empty "" what would it be the problem?

Comment: Do you need the double slashes? since you have the @ at the beginning, it might be reading the directory wrong. Still seems that it would show up in debug mode, but figured I'd ask to make sure.

Comment: did u close the ms access when running the site? may be permissions issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- connection string declared for connecting the web application with MS Access 2007 -->
    <!-- connection string for MS Access 2007 accdb file -->
    <add name="AccessConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|db1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and from the code behind use this

```
import namespaces
using system.data.oledb;

// to access the connection string stored in the web.config file.
OleDbConnection myDataConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

reply if it is useful or not

Comment: I took care of it for you but can format your code by selecting it and then pressing the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that the database property of conn is empty "" what would it be the problem

No that's expected. If you used the OleDbConnection on an RDMS that had multiple database for one server then it would have a value.

For example SQL Server, Sybase, MySQL basically any thing that has a connection that looks like

`Provider = ; Server = ; Database = ;`

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not very sure if this would work.......but u may try this. Check the value of AutoEventWireUp in the .aspx page. If it is set to "false"....set it to "true".